# C# object pooling flaw - all indices are the same?

Tags: c#, object, memory, reference

I wrote an object pooling system a long time ago (well, most of one - just the parts I needed at the time). Now that the program has evolved over it, I've found a flaw that I don't think I had when I implemented the pool.

Essentially the pool takes an object as a constructor and clones it with reflection to make an array of that object. Here's the implementation of the function which creates objects in the pool:

```
        poolSize i = 0;
        T[] oldData = null;

        if (this.chunks != null && this.chunks.Length > 0)
        {
            oldData = new T[this.depth];
            Array.Copy(this.chunks, oldData, this.chunks.Length);
        }

        this.chunks = new T[this.depth + this.depthIncrement];

        if (oldData != null)
        {
            Array.Copy(oldData, this.chunks, oldData.Length);
        }

        for (i = this.depth; i < this.depth + this.depthIncrement; i++)
        {

            this.chunks[i] = Cloner.CloneObjectWithIL(this._template);
            this.freeQueue.Add(i);
        }

        this.depth += this.depthIncrement;
```

Now, checking Object.ReferenceEquals(pool.chunks[0], pool.chunks[1]) returns false - so it appears that each index of the array is its own object, and not just a bunch of references to one object.

Now in the main code we fetch an object from the pool, using the GetObject method:

```
    public T GetObject(T tmp)
    {
        T retObj = tmp;

        this.chunks[this.volume] = retObj;
        this.usedQueue.Add(this.volume);
        this.volume++;

        return retObj;
    }
```

I was having some protected memory errors (C# equivalent of a SEGFAULT?) so I went on to do some debugging. So I use code that I normally wouldn't do, since it defeats some of the purpose behind the pool:

```
Map.Entity tmp = Map.Entity.EntityPool.chunks[0];
tmp.SetPosition(m, 1, 9);
```

Now, when I add a breakpoint after that and look at the chunks array, the position of every element of the chunks array is (1, 9), when they all should be (0, 0) except index 0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I do not believe your code is sufficient to diagnose the problem -- it is too dependent on identifiers declared outside of the scope of your little snippet.  Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Kirk, thanks for the SSCCE reference.

Comment: I've found the flaw. The "deep clone" system I used wasn't actually "deep", so because the "position" property was a reference type all of the "position" properties referred to the same position.Sorry about the SSCCE non-compliance, but the code is very complex and would require several classes to complete. I'll keep that in mind next time.